# 2009 Macbook, question mark at boot and at boot cd

Tags: macos, mac, boot, usb, osx-lion

I am attempting to repair a 2009 Macbook.

Specs: http://support.apple.com/kb/SP504

At boot a grey folder with a question mark appears.  In order to repair the disk, I have tried booting from a Lion Boot CD as well as a Lion USB stick.  The Mac fails to recognize the CD when option is held at boot. The USB stick is recognized but eventually returns a blinking question mark when I attempt to boot from it.

Any suggestion on how to proceed, or any advice? Would this point to logic board failure? Should I try replace the internal HD with a working HD with install of OSX?

Comment: Please give reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be hard drive failure.  I tested it separately and found it was bad.  I replaced hard drive and re installed system.